# Capacitor: curved terminal

Tags: circuitikz, capacity

I'm drawing an equivalent circuit of a Triode (Vacuum Tube) using `circuitikz`. Here is my code:

```latex
\ctikzset{tubes/width=2.8, tubes/height=4, tubes/fill=cyan, tubes/thickness=4}
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=1.1, inductors/scale=1.2}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) node (start) {}
  ++(0,2+\ctikzvalof{tubes/height})
  to[L=$L_g$,o-] ++(2,0) to[R=$R_g$] ++(4,0)
  node[triode,anchor=control] (Tri) {} ++(2,0)
  (Tri.cathode) to[R=$R_c$,-] (Tri.cathode |- start) to[L=$L_c$,-o] ++(0,-2)
  (Tri.anode) to[R=$R_a$] ++(0,4) to [L=$L_a$,-o] ++(0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
```

Now I'd like to draw parasitic capacitors with "curved/rounded" terminals. e.g. like this:
[image: Equivalent circuit vacuum tube - Triode]
Is it possibile using `circuitikz`? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really there is no provision for elements on curved paths in `circuitikz`, but you can use the `node` form of the capacitor and do a bit of manual fiddling. If you add at the end of your snippet:

```latex
  \coordinate (a) at ([xshift=-0.5cm]Tri.control);
  \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=0.5cm]Tri.anode);
  \coordinate (c) at ([xshift=.7cm, yshift=-.7cm]a|-b);
  \node [capacitorshape, rotate=45](C1)  at (c){};
  \draw (a) to[out=90, in=225] (C1.left) (C1.right) to[out=45, in=180] (b);
  \path (C1.center) ++(-0.6,0.6) node{$C_\mathit{ga}$};
```

you'll obtain:

[image]

...the rest of the parasite capacitances is left to the reader... ;-)

Comment: Really useful! [SOLVED]